# posing armature after camera cut

Tags: armature, keyframes, pose-mode

I'm trying to pose my armature in a scene directly after a jump-cut. Its mostly static until the cut and i want its location and armature pose to be completely different. Unfortunately, every time I pose and move it, when I go back to check the previous scenes, hes in his original spot but standing the pose I had just completed. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem, I think that you have set some bones keyframes at the end of the first static part (lets say frame 100), then  - on the next frame (101) - you moved the armature in another location and posed and keyframed it, but when you come back the location of your meshes are not as expected.

This is probably due to the fact that even if you set a keyframe on all bones of your armature, the location of the whole armature object is not recorded. To do so, you'll have to set on frame 100 a keyframe of the loc (and maybe rot and scale) of the whole armature (in object mode), then switch to pose mode, select all bones and set a keyframe; then - on frame 101 - move the armature, set a loc (rot scale) keyframe in object mode, then switch to pose mode, pose the mesh, select all bones and set a keyframe.

Another (more usual) method is not to move anything in object mode during the animation process, and move everything using bones only.

If this doesn't solve your problem I suggest you to upload your file.

Comment: I'll try it out though I may just render everything before the cut, then do the animation and render after the cut. Thanks.